# WebStorm не принимает гит

Tags: git, webstorm

Ошибка, когда пытаюсь подключить гит. Что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: думаю, для начала нужно поменять тему этой чудной программы, чтобы был виден текст ошибки.

Comment: @KoVadim  проблема в том что там нету текста ошибки  менял - нету

Comment: И путь к гиту, указанный выше правильный, и его можно отдельно в консоли запустить?

Comment: @KoVadim всё было правильно ) решилась проблема сменой винды и установкой наново всего :) решил не мелочиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решилась проблема сменой Windows и установкой наново всего